# Vuejs : rendering dynamic link in a button base on probs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a create button above my table, I'm trying to render dynamic `:to` v-bind

Since I have access to `{{title}}`

> Ex. {{title}} = apple, orange, any string

I've tried

```
<router-link :to=`${title}/create`>
    <v-btn color="blue white--text mt-5 mr-8">
        <span>Create</span>
    </v-btn>
</router-link>
```

I get

[image]

---

Try #2

to="{title}/create"

link redirect wrong!

> http://localhost:8080/%7Btitle%7D/create

---

Try #3

to="{{title}}/create"

crashed !!

Comment: You are missing tag quotes: `:to="\`${title}/create\`"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```html
<router-link :to="`${title}/create`">
    <v-btn color="blue white--text mt-5 mr-8">
        <span>Create</span>
    </v-btn>
</router-link>
```

vue-directives are ALWAYS wrapped with double-quotes, even if you are using template literal

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<router-link :to="`${title}/create`">
```